# Virtual Host Configuration Problem

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have Ubuntu running with Apache2, my website shows in browser when www.example.com but doesn't show when example.com, my website is in `/home/username/public_html/example.com/public`.

I used following, which doesnt work

```
sudo bash -c "cat >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com <<EOF

<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName  www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html/example.com/public

</VirtualHost>

EOF"
```

Answer (score -1):

You should look into `/etc/hosts`. You need to include both:

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.com 
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Eh, no, he doesn't have problem with the hosts, but with the virtual host.